# How to select top item of QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I created QTableView as below and want to select the top item as default selection.

```
proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(d->model);

    d->ui->projects->setModel(proxyModel);
    d->ui->projects->setSortingEnabled(true);
    proxyModel->setFilterCaseSensitivity( Qt::CaseInsensitive );
    proxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(-1);

    connect(d->ui->projects->model(),SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),d,SLOT(selectTopOne()));
connect ( d->ui->search_phrase, SIGNAL( textChanged(QString)),
              proxyModel, SLOT( setFilterWildcard(QString)) );
```

Note that **d->ui->projects** represents my QTableView. and **d->ui->projects** is text edit use to grab search string.

I tried to select top item of my table view by calling Slot selectTopOne through the dataChanged signala. But it is not calling for Slot.

And I tried to select row with Qmodelindex (0,0). But it not worked too.

EDIT:

This is How my QTableview appears now.

[image]

This is What I need to do. I need to select first row automatically.

[image]

According to the Text Edit on top items of QTableview filtered. I want to select top item at that time too.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your "selectTopOne()" is called?

Comment: It is a SLOT and connected to dataChanged SIGNAL of model. I debug the code. But breakpoint inside selectTopOne() not hit.

Comment: So that the problem that your selectTopOne not fired. What is d->ui->projects type (you said textfield, but I don't understand what is textfield exactly) ?

Comment: Intially, list of projects with their details appears in the QTableView. One row represents one project. I can select one row at a time. So first, I need to select top project of that list by default. Text Edit (sorry not textfield :( ) use to grab string to filter the items of QTableView. At the time of filtering I need to select top item as well.

Comment: After I read again your question and I still don't understand. Its looks like you have 2 table view.
But the one should be connect to slot selectTopOne is QTextEdit's valueChanged signals. So you select top one slot will be fired when you edit the filter.

Comment: No. one table view. I edit my question. I think now it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer will help you.

```
ui.tableView->selectRow(0);
ui.tableView->setFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use dataChange() signal to set default selection? Am I right that you want select top item by default on start the program? You can just use selection model, for example:

```
 d->ui->projects->selectionModel()->select(d->ui->projects->model()->index(0,0), QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

**AFTER YOUR EDIT:**

OK, I've got it. The decision (for example) is inheritance from `QSortFilterProxyModel` class. There you can use some SLOT that will be use `setFilterRexExp()` (or smth else probably) when you'll change text in `QLineEdit`. After that sending some SIGNAL from this SLOT that you can catch from your main class and call method that I wrote upper, which select first item. Or, if you don't use model index's data do:

```
d->ui->projects->setCurrentIndex(d->ui->projects->model()->index(0,0));
```

Comment: Becoz I want to select topmost item at the time it filter projects according to the input from user.